# How to redirect domain hosted on the same server to subpage on another domain

Tags: redirect, dns, cpanel

I have 3 domains, on one there is a website built, the other two are merely placeholders for branding purposes. Currently the other two merely point their DNS records to the IP address where the primary domain has its website.

I would like to redirect the two domains to specific respective pages on the website of the primary domain. ie: placeholder-domain1.com -> mainwebsite.com/brand1 and placeholder-domain2.com -> mainwebsite.com/brand2

I have tried modifying the redirects in cPanel but they do not seem to be working... Possibly because the domain DNS records still point to the IP address where the main website is. I have full cPanel access but not WHM in case that matters.

Thanks in advance :)